# ASP.Net Checkbox Confirm Message not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have got a checkbox and want to display the confirmation message when it is clicked

I added the event binding in Code Behind file as below.

```
chkSMTLock.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ConfirmSMTLock();");
```

The following is my HTML code for **chkSMTLock**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSMTLock" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSMTLock_CheckedChanged" Text="SMT Lock" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function ConfirmSMTLock() {
        var r = confirm('Are you sure that you want to SMT lock/unlock this account?');

        console.log(r);
        return r;
    }
```

When I run it, I can see the confirmation values (true/ false) in the browser console logs, but, it's not calling any server side code.

My server side code is very simple with logging...

```
protected void chkSMTLock_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Utils.Debug("chkSMTLock_CheckedChanged");
    }
```

When I remove javascript event binding for the checkbox, it executes the ServerSide event successfully.  But When I put it back, it stops working.

How can I use the confirmation message box to control it?

Comment: have you considered using `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Comment: Have you tried using the `onchange` attribute instead of `onclick`?

Comment: If I changed it to 'onchange' it execute the code, even though the return value from the 'confirm' is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out an answer.  Since AutoPostBack = true, it will automatically send a post back to the server.  So, first you need to delete that attribute from the html code.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSMTLock" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkSMTLock_CheckedChanged" Text="SMT Lock" />
```

Then implement the PostBack behaviour by using the **__doPostBack** function of ASP.Net.

```
function ConfirmSMTLock() {
        var r = confirm('Are you sure that you want to SMT lock/unlock this account?');

        if (r == true)
        {
            __doPostBack("chkSMTLock", '');            
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Open Sasame!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your validation is too far down the chain. As you've got AutoPostBack=true, you're basically submitting a form when clicking the checkbox, your validation wants to be at the form level.

```
Form.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ConfirmSMTLock();");
```

And in ConfirmSMTLock() check the status of the checkbox to see if you need to fire the confirm dialogue. That's the simplest way I can think of.

On a side note: if you do this:

```
chkSMTLock.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

The checkbox becomes untickable